# What tool can preview console font?

Tags: linux, console, fonts

I don't know about the console font format, for a normal truetype font, I could use gnome-font-viewer to preview it, but what about console font? If I don't switch back to another tty, and use setfont command, is there a way to view it in X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's any widely-used tool. Try [psfedit](http://www.heckmeck.de/computerstuff/psf_tools/). There's also [NAFE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nafe/) which lets you convert between console fonts and an ASCII pixel representation, or [Cse](http://dt.prohosting.com/hacks/cse.html) to edit a font from the console. I haven't used any of these, so I'm not particularly recommending them, just mentioning their existence.

Answer (score 0):

I use `fp`, a command line tool find it here: https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/fontpreview

Can used also like python module.

A simple example:

```
from fontpreview import FontPreview

fp = FontPreview('/tmp/noto.ttf')
fp.save('/tmp/fp.png')
```

Comment: The question is about console fonts, which are a different format than the TrueType fonts that this supports.

Answer (score -1):

I found a script from somewhere.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# From klaus.stehle@uni-tuebingen.de Tue Jan 25 07:24:02 2000
#
# A small shell script version of the `showconsolefont' C program
#

echo -e "\033%G"
for L in "0 2 4 6" "1 3 5 7"; do
    for P in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do
    for U in 0 1 2 3; do
        for K in $L; do
        echo -ne "  \357\20$U\2$K$P"
        done
    done
    echo
    done
    echo
done
echo -ne "\033%@"
```

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: Looks like when run on Linux console, that just selects Unicode mode and displays the U+0800 .. U+08FF characters of the *current* font, if I'm not mistaken. I understand the original poster wanted a display of *another* console font file. Also, switching back to non-Unicode mode at the end might be inappropriate on modern distributions. However, that might be an useful starting point - thanks for digging that up!